# Show All Slide Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this jquery script that i can't get to work like i want, i want a button that shows all the content at the same time and hides the content at the same time.

When pressing a link, i want all the slides to slide out, and show all the content, and pressing it again will hide it. Is this possible?

I've tried to create a link that run

```
javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes1')
javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes2')
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F48AT/4/)

Comment: do you need to show all div at once?

Comment: Yes, i want one button on top that says Show/hide all, and still the possibility to press the other link that just opens that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
   $(this).slideToggle(400);
}
```

Remove the above **`if`** condition, which is preventing to slide both elements.

```
 $('.newboxes2').each(function (index) {       
            $(this).slideToggle(400);
    });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/F48AT/3/)

Comment: I still want the possibility to slide each content. I just want to add a Show/Hide all button.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/F48AT/5/ You use

```
$(this).slideToggle(400);
```

here the this scope refers to the current clicked item. Since you want all slides to open, you need to use a class common for all slides. In your case this is .newboxes2. Therefore this code opens all slides:

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes2').slideToggle(400);
}
```

Comment: I still want the possibility to slide each one individually, and a button that show/hides all the boxes.
http://jsfiddle.net/F48AT/8/